# Sports club websites

Tags: website-design, design, web, sitemap, process

We have a league website and within that site you can drill down to club sites.
The problem is though, when clicking on a club site, the header will stay on the league site, but the content in the centre changes to display the info, as this is an automated page with all the club info.

It essentially looks like an iframe and looks disjointed. And to the user it looks like two sites in one.

There is no way the user can tell what league the user has clicked from.

The only logical thing I can add in is a breadcrumb, but what else can I add to make this a more seamless process?

Comment: Can you share a link or a screenshot?

Comment: Two clarifying questions : Is there only one league or several ? When you say "There is no way the user can tell what league the user has clicked from.", did you mean "... what club..." or do you mean that although the league header remains, it does not display information about what league the chosen club belongs to ?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I will try to post up a screenshot when I get a chance. There are several leagues, I guess what I meant is that the user has selected the league in the dropdown, you are then presented with the league table, the teams in the table are clickable. once you click on the team, you are then presented with the iframe-style page with populated data about the team, but no way of getting back...and lost in the site, where the top navigation does not correspond to anything on the current page

Comment: Yeah, I think your need more details to get a good answer. How many leagues and the range of teams per league. And how many items are in the navigation for each. A screenshot might answer all of those. Also, "looking disjointed" could be more of a visual design problem than an IA problem.

Answer (score 1):

Could you do something like the NFL do, where you can navigate to any of the teams' sites from the homepage using a small, unobtrusive navigation bar from the top of every page?

To me, this doesn't make the rest of the page look like a disjointed iframe.

Of course, yours would be the opposite, so (a condensed version of) your league site's navigation would sit across the top of every team site, allowing people to get back to your website from anywhere.

As long as it was unobtrusive so as not to clash with the team site navigation, perfectly clear that it was separate from the team's content, and possibly even removable, i.e. a `[x] Remove this Menu` button situated at the end, then I think you would be safe.

The trick would be to determine **which** pages of the league site people would like to go back to from a team site and only include those options within your extra navigation.

[image: NFL Game Pass]

Answer (score 1):

It's called [extra site navigation](http://books.google.com/books?id=LC0cG-vFJbcC&pg=PA99&lpg=PA99&dq=%22extra%20site%20navigation%22&source=bl&ots=CXe__qkS7b&sig=l569ftXCskZ5EJmDACNc6bY0a3Q&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ZgAzVJiPFKeEjAK0kYG4BQ&ved=0CCoQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22extra%20site%20navigation%22&f=false). Just connect users to other team sites via navigation that resides on every unique domain/site. This is also used when a parent company (e.g., sears, etc.) connects users to their brands (e.g, lands' end, etc.).

Examples of extra site navigation:

- [Sears](http://www.sears.com) (top bar with brand logos))
- [ESPN](http://www.espn.com) (e.g., editions, cities, etc.)
- [Yahoo!](http://www.yahoo.com) (top navigation connects users to other properties but it's not persistent)
- [Disney](http://www.disney.com) (e.g., tv, music, games, etc.)